# NHibernate IList as a Drop Down datasource?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, datasource

I'm attempting to populate a drop down from an Nhibernate object, but having problems getting it working properly.  I've created the object and mapped it using the following

```
public class Status
{
    public virtual int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual string StatusName { get; set; }

}
```

...

```
<class name="CM.Core.Status, CM.Core" table="refStatus">
    <id name="StatusId" column="statusId" type="Int32">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
<property name="StatusName" column="status" type="string"/>
</class>
```

I then populate it using

```
    public IList<Status> GetStatuses()
    {
        return _session.CreateQuery("select s from Status s")
            .List<Status>();
    }
```

Finally, I populate my dropdown using

```
        IList<Status> status = _provider.GetStatuses();
        ddlStatus.DataSource = status;
        ddlStatus.DataBind();
```

However, it populates the values and text with my class name instead of the status values the correct number of times
CM.Core.Status
CM.Core.Status
CM.Core.Status
CM.Core.Status

Is IList the incorrect collection type to be used in this situation?  Should I be casting it as something different?  Is there a way to access the class properties prior to databind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the data text fields and data value fields.

```
   ddlStatus.DataTextField = "StatusName";
   ddlStatus.DataValueField = "StatusId";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
ddl.DisplayMember = "StatusName";
ddl.ValueMemeber = "StatusId";
```